# Show/hide text not working using ionic2

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I am having username and password fields. i want to provide **show/hide** password text options for user. I created the code in [this plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/QyZReoVii5ffxVqSR3JV?p=catalogue)

```html
<ion-content class="has-header" padding>    
 <form>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text">  </ion-input>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item *ngIf="passTextHide">
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" class="showhideinput">  </ion-input>
      <span (click)="toggleShow($event)" item-right>Show</span>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngIf="passTextShow">
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" class="showhideinput">  </ion-input>
     <span (click)="toggleShow($event)" item-right>Hide</span>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <button type="submit" primary block>submit</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

The click event was happening but i am not able to see any text change inside password field.

Comment: I added some debug output https://plnkr.co/edit/x0sk7FkkZQC0Zd8HoLNL?p=preview. Switching between `passTextHide` and `passTextShow` is working fine but I don't get what text you expect to change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple as this :

html:

```
<ion-input type={{type}} class="showhideinput">{{hideorshow}} </ion-input>

  <button (click)="toggleShow($event)" item-right>{{hideorshow}}</button>
```

code:

```
  hideorshow="SHOW"
    type="password";


    toggleShow(){
       var state=  this.type

    if(state==="password"){

      this.type='text';
      this.hideorshow="HIDE";

    }
    else{

      this.type="password"
      this.hideorshow="SHOW"
    }
   }
```

Comment: thanks @JS_astronauts, but it is not happening for first click. but it is working for susequent clicks.

Comment: on this plunker it works, is this the functionality you are looking for?